# What happens to the files downloaded by studio after adding a new maven and dependency?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, dependencies

Some times we need to add external repositories using maven and dependency. When we add the line of adding those libraries Android studio starts download some files from external sources. I want to know in which place/folder in the project the files are stored?

And if I remove the maven and dependency line then What happens with the files (the downloaded files)?? Is it deleted automatically with line removal?

Comment: In Linux they're downloaded in ~/.gradle. And no, they're not deleted upon removal.

Comment: Do they stay in the app after final build after removing the dependency?

Comment: No, I meant they stay in your computer filesystem. Removed libraries are not included in APK of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are downloaded in the .gradle directory. If you remove them they stay in the pc but not in the project anymore. The Final build won't have any resources from removed dependency.